# How to get expiration date for an ENS domain

Tags: web3js, ens

I'm using the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-ens-namehash to try to generate an  ID so I can look up an ENS domain's expiration date on the base registrar implementation.

if I hash "vitalik.eth" I get "0xee6c4522aab0003e8d14cd40a6af439055fd2577951148c14b6cea9a53475835"

```
var namehash = require('eth-ens-namehash')
var hash = namehash.hash('vitalik.eth')
```

If I query nameExpires at: https://etherscan.io/address/0x57f1887a8BF19b14fC0dF6Fd9B2acc9Af147eA85#readContract

it returns 0 because it can't find it. I looked up the same record on thegraph: https://thegraph.com/legacy-explorer/subgraph/ensdomains/ens

```
{
  domains(where: {name:"vitalik.eth"}) {
    id
    name
    labelName
    labelhash
  }
}
```

I see the id/namehash, but I also see a labelhash: 0xaf2caa1c2ca1d027f1ac823b529d0a67cd144264b2789fa2ea4d63a67c7103cc

```
{
  "data": {
    "domains": [
      {
        "id": "0xee6c4522aab0003e8d14cd40a6af439055fd2577951148c14b6cea9a53475835",
        "labelName": "vitalik",
        "labelhash": "0xaf2caa1c2ca1d027f1ac823b529d0a67cd144264b2789fa2ea4d63a67c7103cc",
        "name": "vitalik.eth"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if I query this inside etherscan, I get the expiration date: 1935676872.

My question is, how do I get to that correct hash programmatically so I can query the expiration date properly?

Comment: `0xaf2caa1c2ca1d027f1ac823b529d0a67cd144264b2789fa2ea4d63a67c7103cc` is just a keccak on the word `vitalik`

Comment: make it an answer and I'll give you credit

Answer (score 1):

Use `keccak` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keccak). A sample will be as shown below.

```
const keccakHelper = require("keccak");
console.log(keccakHelper("keccak256").update("vitalik").digest("hex"));
```